# How can I get the Lync Meeting URL programmatically in C#?

Tags: exchangewebservices, lync, ucma, lync-client-sdk, lync-2013

Currently I am running an ASP.NET web application and my web page needs to provide a button to get the Lync Meeting URL just like the Outlook does:

Please see the screenshot here: [Lync Meeting Address in Outlook](http://apworks.org/wp-content/uploads/lync_meet_url.png)

The behavior of this button is when it is clicked, the Lync Meeting URL is retrieved (maybe from the Exchange server) and is shown on a asp:Label control on the web page.

I googled but I have been told that there are three SDKs can be considered for this scenario:

1. Lync SDK - seems the Lync client must be running while the SDK is in use
2. Microsoft Unified Communications Managed API (UCMA)
3. Microsoft Exchange Web Services (EWS)

I am really confused on these three SDKs, and don't know how to achieve my goal by utilizing these SDKs, could someone please help me? It would be much appreciate if you can post some sample code here.

Thank you!

Comment: You want the Unified Communications Web API, google it and you get some nice sample code :)

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a similar solution(winform application) on UCMA. But you need a trusted application server to run such program.

Answer (score 0):

1. Connect to Exchange and retrieve the user's meeting schedule using Exchange WebServices (like you said with EWS), there is a property that hold the meeting URL in each meeting object, here is a good overview https://mohamedasakr.wordpress.com/2012/05/16/get-lync-online-meetings-information-using-the-ews-managed-api-2/
2. Make sure you are connected to the Lync Server and signed in. there are a bunch of good tutorials in the "How To" tab on the MSDN Lync 2013 guide
3. Once you have an instance of LyncClient initialized, call

   ```
   yourLyncClientInstanceConversationManager.AddConversation();
   ```
4. In your Conversation added event handler, use

   ```
   yourLyncClientInstance.ConversationManager.JoinConference(exchangeUrl);
   ```