# Lync SDK 2013 - Join the scheduled meeting using meet.lync.com url

Tags: exchangewebservices, lync, skype-for-business, lync-2013, lync-client-sdk

I retrieve the scheduled meeting url from exchange online server (office 365) in the following format - https://meet.lync.com/organization/username/Y0RR3HTK.

How can I join to this meeting using Lync SDK 2013 (not launching url in the browser)?

The following code accepts the url in the format - "conf:sip:userUri;gruu;opaque=app:conf:focus:id:conferenceId?"

```
Automation.BeginStartConversation(meetingUrl, 0, StartConversation_Callback, null);
```

PS. I have tried to create meeting in my organization, and it returned another format - "https://meet.domain.ru/username/YTHJ145B" - and it can be easily converted to "conf:sip" format (username@domain.ru is userUri, but in problem scenario 1 username@organization or username@lync.com is not the userUri);

PSS. This suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/a/31410399/4377953 doesn't work, I get the exception without any details while calling `LyncClient.ConversationManager.JoinConference("https://meet.lync.com/organization/username/Y0RR3HTK");`

Answer (score 0):

While using `LyncClient.ConversationManager.JoinConference(meetingUrl)` use meeting url in format "conf:sip:userUri;gruu;opaque=app:conf:focus:id:conferenceId?" itself and replace *sip:userUri* with `lyncClient.Self.Contact.Uri` as given in the following code

```
string meetingLink = "https://meet.domain.ru/username/YTHJ145B";
string[] linktokens = meetingLink.Split('/');
string joinUri = "conf:" + lyncClient.Self.Contact.Uri + ";gruu;opaque=app:conf:focus:id:" + linktokens.Last() + "?";
conversation = lyncClient.ConversationManager.JoinConference(joinUri);
```